# Trying to change the status bar style is giving me error in ios - React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[image]

I did some research about it and I found the ios file, but didn't know how to change it exactly.

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
```

Which part I should set to yes? There is only a false tag. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What it means to make it YES, is similar to making the false tag to true tag,

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <true/>
```

Alternatively,
If you use xcode, go to your Info.plist, check for the key **View controller-based status bar appearance**, its default value would be NO, make it YES. come back and check it in your vscode, you will see that false tag got converted to true.

Answer (score 0):

the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance require value set to NO

so this issue is the react-native-screen problem if you use react-native-navigation v6 you should use all their modules

for me I change this line from

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from 'react-native-screens/native-stack';
```

to

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
```